# XPath $variable instead of text()

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

I am using the following XPath search:

```html
$var = '';

$search = $selector->query('//td[text() = "text"]/following-sibling::td')->item(0);
```

How to use $var instead of "text"?

query('//td[text() = $var]

Comment: I find working with XPath much easier in JavaScript. May not fit for what you need today, but good to know for the future. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

Comment: What's the programming language and specific XPath library you're using? A better solution may be available, if given those details; the existing one won't work if, for instance, the text being substituted includes literal double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know which language that is, assuming `.` as the infix concat operator:

```
$search = $selector->query('//td[text() = "'.$var.'"]/following-sibling::td');
```

**Update**:

As Charles Duffy pointed out, the given solution has shortcomings. Caveat: This section is untested code devised purely according to the php docs (namely [this one](http://php.net/manual/de/domxpath.registerphpfunctions.php)). Feel free to improve/delete.

```
$var = '';

function get_var() {
    // Return variable $var
    return $var;
}
$selector->registerPHPFunctions("get_var");
$search = $selector->query('//td[text() = php:function("get_var")]/following-sibling::td');
```

Comment: Most XPath engines have proper support of out-of-band variables that don't risk query injection (like this answer does). This is thus suboptimal an both correctness and security -- it's the XPath equivalent of Bobby Tables (granted, there's no DROP TABLE operation in XPath, but one can still inject code that modifies a query to select information the user isn't supposed to see).